# Making a class only possess predefined states

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I'm programming a rudimentary for an attacking submarine, and I want to have a variable which tells me which *state* the AI is in, e.g. Attacking, Retreating.

I know it's possible to use a `string` but I'm certain I've seen another way of doing it before, like `Submarine.AIstate = AIstate.Attacking`. Sorry if it seems like a basic question, but I'm pretty new to this kind of thing.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You're thinking of enumerations I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks so much! :D

Comment: No problem! I'd suggest looking at, using and accepting one of the examples given below :-)

Comment: @Cogythea welcome to stackoverflow. You can now google `C#` `Enum` and find plenty of documents. You can upvote the answers you find helpful. You can also accept an answer and be rewarded reputation for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum`s.

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Basically, you would have an `enum` that represents the state:

```
enum SubState {
    Idle = 0,
    Attacking,
    Retreating
}
```

Then you sub would have a property for the state:

```
class Submarine {
    public SubState State { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can set the state like this:

```
sub.State = SubState.Attacking;
```

..and check it like this:

```
switch (sub.State) {
    case SubState.Attacking:
         // do attacking stuff here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an enum with your states:

```
public enum AIState
{
   Attacking,
   Retreating
}
```

and a property on your Submarine class of that type:

```
public AIState AIState
{
  get; set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you want to achieve is using `enum`

```
public class Submarine
{
    public enum AIState
    {
        Attacking = 0,
        Retreating = 1
    }

    public AIState CurrentAIState { get; set; }

    // # Your fields, properties, constructor, methods here

    public void DecideNextMove()
    {
        if (CurrentAIState == AIState.Attacking)
        {
            // Decide
        }
        else if (CurrentAIState == AIState.Retreating)
        {
            // Decide
        }
    }
}
```

You may choose to use `switch` block instead of `if else` block as i did. And if you want to change current state of *Submarine* you can use property setter as `CurrentState = AIState.Attacking`